# Why does my Powershell 7 color scheme not match my settings?

Tags: powershell, colors, profile, psreadline

I just started actively learning PowerShell, day 1 non-programmer following "Learn PowerShell in a Month of Lunches." Chapter 1 tells me to customize my command prompt, so I do. Except this is what happens. Here's what typing in some values gives me:
[example of test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiQYP.png).

Also important to note, I have created a profile with
[some attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yE9J.png).

So, please forgive me for being absolutely fish out of the water when I'm trying my very first lesson at PowerShell, but what gives? I understand the background being grey and initial text being black, because I set that [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK0vW.png). But I can't figure out why the text swaps to red, when there is no error, and why ^C is colored in a faint pink when no attribute in PSReadLineOption indicates such a color.

Thank you for being patient and understanding with me, I'm really excited to give PowerShell my best to begin my automation journey but something as simple as setting colors already has me lost.